# Environment variables not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, carrierwave

I just set up a server on ec2 and installed all that was needed. 
Trying to start my rails app from the app's root dir in the ec2 instance using

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

gives me an error which suggests that my environment variables aren't loading

`validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)

I have this in my ~/.bashrc

```
export S3_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXX"
export S3_SECRET="XXXXXXXXX"
export S3_REGION="XXXXX"
export S3_BUCKET="XXXXX"
```

Doing `source ~/.bashrc`
makes the `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` command work
and I can `curl localhost:3000` to see my homepage html

all the commands have been run on the server after ssh-ing into it.

Shouldn't these environment variables be loaded automatically when I connect to the server using ssh? 
Am I correct in assuming that since they don't seem to be loaded unless I manually `source ~/.bashrc`, my web server will not have access to them either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This bit was missing in `~/.profile` on this newly setup server for some reason. Usually this is there by default.

This was causing my `~/.bashrc` to not load up at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a way to make it work, I'd recommend you to use dotenv. It's very easy to configure.

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

In database.yml:

```
username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
password: <%= ENV['DB_PASS'] %>
etc ...
```

Then you just create in the main folder a file named .env with your configuration:

```
DB_USER = XXXX
DB_PASS = XXXX
etc ...
```

There is also something optional to add in application.rb.

Full documentation:
https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

An useful article:
http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-guide-environment-variables/

Comment: With the above configuration, it still won't work in production! Here is why https://amitpatel.xyz/doenv-not-loading-environment-variables-in-production/